# Can't display a form in embed view

Tags: php, html, forms, symfony, twig

I got an issue to display a form in popup view. I have read the Symphony documentation and created a bundle to store my form. Then in the base controller I have tried to load it...

I got the following error:
Variable "form" does not exist in nostalgie90sloginUserBundle:Default:loginUser.html.twig at line 1

I want to display this form in a popup using leanModal jquery

The base file where the main view is loaded 
base.html.twig:

```
//some stuff of the base
 //....
 <div id="loginmodal" style="display:none;">
<p> MON FORMULAIRE </p>
                    <!--{{ include ("nostalgie90sloginUserBundle:Default:loginUser.html.twig") }} -->
                        {{ render(controller('nostalgie90sloginUserBundle:Default:new')) }}                             

             </div>
            </a>
```

My controller where the form is loaded:

```
class DefaultController extends Controller//login bundle
{

   public function newAction()
   {
    $user = new User90s();
    $form = $this->createForm(new LoginForm(), $user);

     return $this->render('nostalgie90sloginUserBundle:Default:loginUser.html.twig',  array('form' => $form->createView(), ));
}

public function indexAction($name)
{

}
}
```

My form class:
     class LoginForm extends AbstractType
{

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('login');
    $builder->add('password');
    $builder->add('mail');
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'login';
}

public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
{
    return array('data_class' => 'nostalgie90s\BaseBundle\Entity\User90s', );
}

 }
```

And finally the view of the form loginUser.html.twig:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_errors(form) }}

{{ form_row(form.login) }}
{{ form_row(form.password) }}

<input type="submit" />
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Comment: Error you described just says, that you didn't pass the `form` var to controller's `render()` method, but according to your code you did it. Any updates to this issue?

Comment: Yeah you totally get it, I don't see why it does not take into account the form, I even check the validity of the form (null or not null)..., When I load only the the controller with form it works but when I try to embed it into another template... Maybe my route are bad ? I did not specify any route for this form as it can be anywhere